# ActiveMQ may not be ready. Service is partially running

Tags: activemq-classic

After installing Avaya Experience Portal in VM Red Hat 64bit, it pops up with an error:

> ActiveMQ may not be ready. Lock file found but no process running for
> pid, continuing

It leads to a service that is partially running at the end.

Can anyone suggest on how to solve this ActiveMQ problem?